# Cómo imprimir objetos de clase padre e hijas

Tags: java, poo, objeto, herencia

tengo este proyecto de Electrodomésticos y clases hijas (usando herencia) Televisor y Lavadora y lo que quería era hacer un for para poder mostrar todos los elementos del array, como podría hacerlo ya que las clases hijas tienen más atributos que el padre?

Si todos los elementos fuesen Electrodomestico no habría problema pero es que al tener clases hijas que heredan y añaden más del padre ya me es más complicado, pienso que con un for y añadir un atributo "tipo" a la clase Electrodomestico podría ir a base de ifs pero me parece poco practico y pienso que algo tiene que tener la herencia para poder hacerlo más simple, saludos.

```
La clase main: 

package electrodomesticos;

import electrodomesticos.Electrodomestico.color_disponible;
import electrodomesticos.Electrodomestico.consumo_energetico;

/**
 *
 * @author pablo
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        float precio, peso, resolucion;
        boolean sintonizador;
        int carga;
        color_disponible color;
        consumo_energetico consumo;

        Electrodomestico[] lista_electrodomesticos = new Electrodomestico[10];
        Electrodomestico electro1 = null;
        Lavadora lava1 = (Lavadora) electro1;
        lava1 = new Lavadora (3.34f, color_disponible.AZUL, consumo_energetico.F, 3.2f, 23232);
        Television teledeculo = new Television (33.2f, color_disponible.NEGRO, consumo_energetico.F, 33.f, 43434, true);
        teledeculo.setPrecioBase(3987432);    //Una tele muuuy cara

        lista_electrodomesticos[1] = electro1;

        lista_electrodomesticos[0] = new Electrodomestico(200, color_disponible.AZUL, consumo_energetico.C, 30);
        lista_electrodomesticos[1] = new Lavadora(150, 30);
        lista_electrodomesticos[2] = new Television(500, color_disponible.BLANCO, consumo_energetico.E, 33, 42, false);
        lista_electrodomesticos[3] = new Electrodomestico();

        for (int i = 0; i < lista_electrodomesticos.length; i++) {
            /*
             * Cuando una Television o una Lavadora este en la posicion del array actual,
             * pasara por su clase y por la de electrodomestico, ya que una television es un electrodomestico.
             * Ejecutamos en cada uno su propia version del metodo precioFinal
             */

            int suma_electrodomesticos = 0, suma_lavadoras = 0, suma_televisiones = 0;

            if (lista_electrodomesticos[i] instanceof Electrodomestico) {
                suma_electrodomesticos += lista_electrodomesticos[i].calcularPrecioFinal();
            }
            if (lista_electrodomesticos[i] instanceof Lavadora) {
                suma_lavadoras += lista_electrodomesticos[i].calcularPrecioFinal();
            }
            if (lista_electrodomesticos[i] instanceof Television) {
                suma_televisiones += lista_electrodomesticos[i].calcularPrecioFinal();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

La clase Electrodomestico:

```
package electrodomesticos;
    
    /**
     *
     * @author pablo
     */
    public class Electrodomestico {
        
        //Atributos
        private float precio_base;
        private color_disponible color;
        private consumo_energetico consumo;
        private float peso;
        
        //Constantes
        public final static float DEF_PRECIO = 100;
        public final static color_disponible DEF_COLOR = color_disponible.BLANCO;
        public final static consumo_energetico DEF_CONSUMO = consumo_energetico.F;
        public final static float DEF_PESO = 5;
        
        //Enums
        public enum color_disponible {
            BLANCO("Blanco"), NEGRO("Negro"), ROJO("Rojo"), AZUL("Azul"), GRIS("Gris");
    
            private String color;
    
            public String getColor() {
                return color;
            }
    
            public void setColor(String color) {
                this.color = color;
            }
    
            private color_disponible(String color) {
                this.color = color;
            }
    
        }
    
        public enum consumo_energetico {
            A('A'), B('B'), C('C'), D('D'), E('E'), F('F');
    
            private char letra_consumo;
    
            public char getLetra_consumo() {
                return letra_consumo;
            }
    
            public void setLetra_consumo(char letra_consumo) {
                this.letra_consumo = letra_consumo;
            }
    
            private consumo_energetico(char letra_consumo) {
                this.letra_consumo = letra_consumo;
    
            }
        }
    
        //Constructores
        public Electrodomestico() {
            this(DEF_PRECIO, color_disponible.BLANCO, consumo_energetico.F, DEF_PESO);
        }
    
        public Electrodomestico(float precio_base, float peso) {
            this(precio_base, color_disponible.BLANCO, consumo_energetico.F, peso);
        }
    
        public Electrodomestico(float precio_base, color_disponible color, consumo_energetico consumo, float peso) {
            this.precio_base = precio_base;
            this.color = color;
            this.consumo = consumo;
            this.peso = peso;
            char consum_letra = consumo.getLetra_consumo();
            comprobarConsumoEnergetico(consum_letra);
            String color_disp = color.getColor();
            comprobarColor(color_disp);
    
        }
    
        //Getters and Setters
        public float getPrecioBase() {
            return precio_base;
        }
    
        public void setPrecioBase(float precio_base) {
            this.precio_base = precio_base;
        }
    
        public float getPeso() {
            return peso;
        }
    
        private void comprobarConsumoEnergetico(char letra_de_consumo) {
            boolean es_letra_correcta = false;
            if (letra_de_consumo == 'A' || letra_de_consumo == 'B' || letra_de_consumo == 'C' || letra_de_consumo == 'D' || letra_de_consumo == 'E' || letra_de_consumo == 'F') {
                es_letra_correcta = true;
            } else {
                this.consumo = DEF_CONSUMO;
            }
        }
    
        private void comprobarColor(String color_a_comprobar) {
            boolean es_color_correcto = false;
            if (color_a_comprobar.equals(color_disponible.values())) {      //Si el color está entre los del enum
                es_color_correcto = true;
            } else {
                this.color = DEF_COLOR;
            }
        }
    
        public double calcularPrecioFinal() {
            double plus = 0;
            consumo_energetico consum_cond = consumo_energetico.A;
            switch (consum_cond) {
                case A:
                    plus += 100;
                    break;
                case B:
                    plus += 80;
                    break;
                case C:
                    plus += 60;
                    break;
                case D:
                    plus += 50;
                    break;
                case E:
                    plus += 30;
                    break;
                case F:
                    plus += 10;
                    break;
            }
    
            if (peso >= 0 && peso < 19) {
                plus += 10;
            } else if (peso >= 20 && peso < 49) {
                plus += 50;
            } else if (peso >= 50 && peso <= 79) {
                plus += 80;
            } else if (peso >= 80) {
                plus += 100;
            }
            return precio_base + plus;
        }
    
    }
    
Las clases Lavadora y Television:
```

lavadora.java

```
package electrodomesticos;

/**
 *
 * @author pablo
 */
public class Lavadora extends Electrodomestico {
    
    private int carga;

    public void setCarga(int carga) {
        this.carga = carga;
    }

    public int getCarga() {
        return carga;
    }
    private final static int DEF_CARGA = 5;
    
    public Lavadora () {
     this(DEF_PRECIO, DEF_COLOR, DEF_CONSUMO, DEF_PESO, DEF_CARGA);
    }
    
    public Lavadora (float precio_base, float peso){
     this(precio_base, DEF_COLOR, DEF_CONSUMO, peso, DEF_CARGA);
    }
    
    public Lavadora (float precio_base, color_disponible color, consumo_energetico consumo, float peso, int carga){
        super(precio_base, color, consumo, peso);
        this.carga = carga;
    }
    
    @Override
    public double calcularPrecioFinal() {
        double plus = super.calcularPrecioFinal();
        if (this.carga>30){
            plus = plus + 50;
        }
        return plus;
        
    }
}
```

Television.java

```
package electrodomesticos;

/**
 *
 * @author pablo
 */
public class Television extends Electrodomestico {
    private float resolucion;

    public float getResolucion() {
        return resolucion;
    }

    public boolean isSintonizador_TDT() {
        return sintonizador_TDT;
    }
    private boolean sintonizador_TDT;
    public static final float DEF_RESO = 20;
    public static final boolean DEF_SINTO = false;
    
    public Television () {
        this(DEF_PRECIO, DEF_COLOR, DEF_CONSUMO, DEF_PESO, DEF_RESO, DEF_SINTO);
    }
    
    public Television (float precio_base, float peso) {
        this(precio_base, DEF_COLOR, DEF_CONSUMO, peso, DEF_RESO, DEF_SINTO);
    }
    
    public Television (float precio_base, color_disponible color, consumo_energetico consumo, float peso, float resolucion, boolean sintonizador_TDT) {
        super(precio_base, color, consumo, peso);
        this.resolucion = resolucion;
        this.sintonizador_TDT = sintonizador_TDT;
    }
    
    @Override
    public double calcularPrecioFinal(){
        double plus = super.calcularPrecioFinal();
    if (this.resolucion > 40){
        plus = plus + getPrecioBase()*0.3;
    }
    if (this.sintonizador_TDT = true){
        plus = plus + 50;
    }
    
    return plus;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: a que te referis con todos los elementos del array? de que array?

Comment: Todo depende para que quieres utilizar esa impresión de datos, si es solo para un log o quieres simular una impresión de detalle con un formato específico en consola, dinos cual es el resultado que espera para darte una solución espesifica.

Comment: @gbianchi me refiero a los objetos Televisor Lavadora Electrodomestico que voy metiendo en la lista_electrodomesticos

Comment: @RobertoEMoran es porque la impresión para imprimir objetos no sé como ir distinguiendo en el for que recorre el array para que vaya distinguiendo si los electrodomesticos son televisores o lavadoras y asi mostrar unos campos u otros ya que no sé como meter si un objeto es de una clase o de otra en un if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que ya lo has solucionado, pero de todas formas te respondo y explico un poco.

Tomando como base que **quieres imprimir** los distintos tipos de electrodomésticos por pantalla, la mejor opción es que todos re definan el método `toString`, que heredan de la clase `Object`. Es decir, no hace falta hacer un `if` en cascada con `instanceof`.

Si ya te han explicado herencia, sabrás que todas las clases que no extienden a otras heredan de la clase `Object`, y que al crear una clase que hereda explícitamente de otra, hereda sus métodos, con la implementación que tuvieran.

En la clase `Object` está definido el método `toString`, que transforma un objeto a su representación textual (generalmente se imprime su `OID` y el nombre canónico de la clase), por lo que convendría re definirlo en la clase `Electrodomestico`, y también en las clases hijas.

Como ejemplo:

```
// Hereda de la clase Object
public class Electrodomestico {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Esto es un electrodoméstico.";
    }
}

public class Televisor extends Electrodomestico {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Esto es un televisor.";
    }
}
```

La duda que no has resuelto es: ¿qué método se ejecuta al llamar a `toString`? ¿El de `Object`, el de `Electrodomestico` o el de `Televisor`? La respuesta está en el **polimorfismo y ligadura dinámica**.

Si declaras una variable de tipo `Electrodomestico` y guardas la referencia a un objeto de tipo `Electrodomestico` en ella, al llamar a `toString`, se ejecutará el método de `Electrodoméstico`, como es natural.

```
Electrodomestico e = new Electrodomestico();  // Instanciamos la clase Electrodomestico
System.out.println(e.toString());  // Imprimirá "Esto es un electrodoméstico."
```

De igual forma, si creas un objeto de tipo `Televisor` y lo almacenas en una variable del mismo tipo, se ejecutará el método de la clase `Televisor`.

```
Televisor t = new Televisor();  // Instanciamos la clase Televisor
System.out.println(t.toString());  // Imprimirá "Esto es un televisor."
```

Ahora bien, cuando tenemos herencia, podemos almacenar un objeto de una clase hija en una variable del tipo del padre. Esto se llama *polimorfismo*. Entonces la variable tiene un tipo declarado (`Electrodomestico`) y un tipo dinámico (`Televisor`), que puede ir cambiando en tiempo de ejecución según el tipo de objeto que asignemos a la variable.

En este contexto se cumple que, si tenemos un método re definido en varias clases, se ejecuta siempre el método del tipo dinámico, es decir, el de la clase hija en nuestro caso.

```
Electrodomestico e = new Televisor();  // Polimorfismo
System.out.println(e.toString());  // Ligadura dinámica: imprime "Esto es un televisor."
```

Por tanto, si guardas objetos de tipo `Electrodoméstico` y de sus hijas, solo te hace falta llamar una vez al métdo `toString`, y se ejecutará el adecuado por ligadura dinámica.

```
List<Electrodomestico> lista = new LinkedList<>();
lista.add(new Electrodomestico());
lista.add(new Televisor());

for (Electrodomestico e : lista) System.out.println(e.toString());
```

El código anterior produce que se ejecute el método `toString` de `Electrodomestico` para el objeto de su tipo dinámico, y el de `Televisor` para el objeto del tipo dinámico correspondiente, incluso aunque se guarden como si fueran todos de la clase padre.

Como apunte final, la implementación de la clase hija puede hacer un uso explícito de la del padre mediante la palabra clave `super`.

```
public class Electrodomestico {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Esto es un electrodoméstico.";
    }
}

public class Televisor extends Electrodomestico {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + " En concreto, es un televisor.";
    }
}
```

Con `super.ToString()` llamamos a la implementación del padre, por lo que el código:

```
Electrodoméstico e = new Televisor();
System.out.println(e.toString());
```

Imprimirá la cadena *"Esto es un electrodoméstico. En concreto, es un televisor."*.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Eequiis Vásquez claro es lo que tiene el polimorfismo que cuando lo recorro se ejecuta el toString() del tipo dinámico del objeto yéndose al toString sobreescrito de la clase hija correspondiente, al final me acabó saliendo porque en los toString de Lavadora y Television hice un super.toString() para llamar además a los atributos de la clase Electrodomestico (padre) así al igual que hiciste al final pude concatenar tanto los del padre como la de las hijas, así que perfecto, gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre que podrías usar un Map para guardar los precios del siguiente modo:

```
Map<String,Integer> precios = new HashMap<>();
for (Electrodomestico e : listaElectrodomesticos) {
  String clase = e.getClass().getName();
  if (precios.containsKey(clase) {
    precios.put(clase, map.get(class) + e.calcularPrecioFinal());
  } else {
    precios.put(clase, e.calcularPrecioFinal());
  }
}
```

Luego sólo tienes que recorrer el Map, obteniendo el nombre de cada clase:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : precios.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
}
```

**Actualización**: Escribí el código directamente aquí, así que no me di cuenta de que no puedes llamar `class` a una variable porque es una palabra reservada de Java. He corregido esa parte.

Viendo con un poco de perspectiva el problema, creo que la forma de modelar los objetos no es la mejor: Si mañana pasas a vender Microondas, necesitarías una clase nueva, no es algo que escale muy bien.

Mi propuesta sería crear una clase Electrodoméstico que tenga un campo que indique qué tipo de electrodoméstico es:

```
public class Electrodomestico {
    
    //Atributos
    private float precio_base;
    private color_disponible color;
    private consumo_energetico consumo;
    private float peso;
    
    private String tipo;
    private String modelo;
    ...//getters y setters
}
```

Y de este modo puedes preguntar a cada electrodoméstico su tipo.

Comment: Ummm eso del HashMap y el Map me pilla algo avanzado todavía, intenté implementarlo ahora y me da errores por todas partes, (lo puse en la clase Main), pero no sé como se haría puff

Comment: no deberia simplemente hacer un override de ToString?

Comment: for(Electrodomestico pos: lista_electrodomesticos){
    if(pos.getClass()=="Televisor"){
        
    }
} //no se podría hacer así, aunque el problema es que no sé como comparar la clase (getClass()) me da error asi

Comment: @gbianchi si pero es que no sé como diferenciar las clases para que el for me vaya imprimiendo una cosa o la otra

Comment: es lo que digo.. tu for no deberia diferenciar nada de nada.. deberias tener un metodo que este sobreescrito en cada clase hija, que sepa como mostrarse... si no, si tuvieras 10 clases hijas, tu case es eterno... no es mejor que cada clase sepa como mostrarse, y solo llames a ese metodo?

Comment: vale te entiendo, para empezar al toString de electrodomestico vale sé llamarlo, el problema viene luego cuando intento diferenciar de llamar al toString de Televisor o Lavadora porque ahí si que tendría que poner cases, vamos, es la única forma que sé hasta ahora

Comment: for(int i=0; i<lista_electrodomesticos.length; i++){
        lista_electrodomesticos[i].toString(); 
        if (lista_electrodomesticos[i] instanceof Lavadora){
           lista_electrodomesticos[i].toString(); 
        }
        else if (lista_electrodomesticos[i] instanceof Television){
            lista_electrodomesticos[i].toString(); 
        }
        else {
            
        }
    }

Comment: No se podría hacer así? con instanceof? Aunque pongo antes la llamada toString a la clase padre luego con las condiciones veo si un objeto es de tal clase se ejecuta el toString de la clase hija.

Comment: Bueno parece que lo he solucionado, ya que con un toString en las clases hijas y la padre luego al emplear solo uno al recorrer el for ya valeee creo

Comment: He actualizado un poco la respuesta, por si te ayuda

Comment: Muchas gracias! Pablo Lozano